# What causes CORDBG_E_CLASS_NOT_LOADED (HRESULT: 0x80131303)

Tags: c#, hresult

While attempting to debug an application, I keep noticing that two of my arrays and one of my lists seems to be mysteriously... Not there. The error given for that (upon pausing the application and looking through my compiler's variable list) is "A class is not loaded HRESULT: 0x80131303".

After googling, I found out that that particular HRESULT is named "CORDBG_E_CLASS_NOT_LOADED", however I found nothing about it's possible cause, or how to solve it.

I would normally paste the relevant code here, but from what I can find, this error happens directly at the declaration of the effected arrays and list.

Can anyone here help?

Comment: List is int, arrays are an int and a bool.

Comment: You make the context of this error much to hard to guess.  Just keep in mind that no class gets loaded until the JIT compiler thinks it is necessary to do so.

Comment: What information could I provide to make the context clearer? Because as far as I know, I've put literally all the information I've got available to me in the question :\.

Comment: I really think you need to post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You may be loading a class implicitly at startup, which causes an error because not everything is initialized yet. Make sure you are not accessing anything in an unloaded class that could cause this.

Comment: How would I be able to tell if I'm loading a class implicitly?

Comment: Go through and make sure no variables or objects of other classes are accessed during initialization. If, for example, you access a variable in a form class before the form is loaded, it will load that form before it is explicitly loaded. Then, when you explicitly load the form, you may have two instances of the form class, which gets confusing.