# CORDBG_E_CLASS_NOT_LOADED (HRESULT: 0x80131303) error with List<double>

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop

I'm creating a List variable. I get this error right when I initialize it like so:

```
List<double> nums = new List<double>();
```

Has anyone else encountered this before? I haven't been able to find very much info about his at all. I'm coding in C# using MonoDevelop.

Comment: I think it may help if you posted more of your code, but have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190333/what-causes-cordbg-e-class-not-loaded-hresult-0x80131303

Comment: I also just found this which I think may be helpful to you, though I'm definitely too new to C# and programming in general to know exactly what to make of it: http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid982EFCD16D20BF0A85FDDE8063987FCFB5C3C833.aspx?s=cdef%3Ahash+table   (search for 'cordbg_e_class_not_loaded')

Comment: @BrianSnow I saw that link... I'm not sure how to make sure I'm not implicitly loading it (or some other class). I'm kinda at the point in learning where I know just enough to be really dangerous and create problems that I can't find answers too, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I switch to Mono runtime in Monodevelop (menu item: "Project / Active Runtime /Mono"), the problem disappears. I created bug report 6124 at bugzilla.xamarin.com. Up to now I'm not aware of any solution / workaround.